# Windows 10 keeps suspending whenever i use keyboard

Tags: windows-10, event-log, suspend

Whenever I'm working on word of at any other place requiring keyboard usage, my windows randomly goes on suspended mode.

I checked the event viewer and it turned out there was some restarting scheduling for the service of software protection, so I deleted all of that.
However the problem still persists, but now instead of the service software protection I found a system log like

"The system is entering in suspension.
Reason of suspension: Button or Lid"

I browsed internet and people seemed to refer to update the drivers, so I went to AMD Ryzen'ssite and updated radeon. But nothing happens... Same thing.

Any ideas how to stop that?

Comment: It could be that there is an intermittent short in the lid button that occurs when tapping at the keyboard. See if the issue occurs when you knock gently on the keyboard itself, without hitting a key.

Answer (score 0):

If this problem only occurs when you type on the keyboard, please switch to onscreen keyboard and type on the onscreen keyboard to see the issue still occurs. If the issue does not appear, it might be a problem with the keyboard itself.